# Create external table hive, location contains multiple files inside

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hive

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (LGACT STRING,NTNAME STRING)  
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/LOGS/test';
```

under 'test' folder I am writing files daily. for eg:

```
/user/hive/warehouse/LOGS/test/20170420
/user/hive/warehouse/LOGS/test/20170421
/user/hive/warehouse/LOGS/test/20170422
```

I cannot see any data inside LOGS table that i have created.

But, I create the table using

```
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/LOGS/test/20170422';
```

I can see that days records.

I want to see all the data under /test directory in my HIVE table, also the /test directory is populated daily with new files.

Comment: I have already answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43804942/2700344

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive create table with inputs from nested sub-directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438148/hive-create-table-with-inputs-from-nested-sub-directories)

Comment: @leftjoin - you are giving a wrong answer there

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz I gave working answer.

Comment: @leftjoin - It is like arguing that the way to restart an old Windows was to press `ctrl`+`alt`+`delete`+`esc`+`space`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

In order to support sub-directories

```
set mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;
```

and if you Hive version is lower than [2.0.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11582) then also

```
set hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=false;
```

**Option 2**

Create a partitioned table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGS (LGACT STRING,NTNAME STRING)  
partitioned by (dt date)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/LOGS/test';
```

---

```
alter table LOGS add if not exists partition (dt=date '2017-04-20') LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/LOGS/test/20170420';
alter table LOGS add if not exists partition (dt=date '2017-04-21') LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/LOGS/test/20170421';
alter table LOGS add if not exists partition (dt=date '2017-04-22') LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/LOGS/test/20170422';
```

It would be easier to manage if you keep your directories using the standard convention, e.g. `dt=2017-04-20` instead of `20170420`

Comment: Thanks. Option 1 does the work. 
But if I do select * on hive command line i can see the data. But if i check the same table using HUE i dont see any records? Do we need to change any config on HUE level ?

Answer (score 0):

By default hive reads only the files (not directories) inside the specified location in external table. If you want to enable adding the directories, then set the below parameter:

set mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;

Comment: This is only a partial answer and the full answer was already given.