# Databricks SQL query nested folders

Tags: azure, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I've been successful at adding azure storage as a source on Azure Databricks.
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html

I've also been successful at creating tables that read a static folder of files.
https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/tables.html

What I want to do is create a table that reads files recursively from folders.

none of these solutions work:

- [Hive create table with inputs from nested sub-directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438148/hive-create-table-with-inputs-from-nested-sub-directories)
- https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/42909/merge-multiple-directories-into-one-table-in-hive.html

Comment: https://medium.com/@cprosenjit/spark-tables-bf4a4c5252b7

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you have tried? By default subfolders are read. If you have multiple root folders you can pass an array of folders in Python or Scala - I doubt SQL will allow an array.

Answer (score 3):

Answering this for any future references, as google pointed me to this page when i was searching for the solution to similar problem :) Try this

create table test45(id bigint)  using parquet location "< parent directory>" OPTIONS(recursiveFileLookup=true);