# How can I add a storage container to Azure with different account?

Tags: azure, hive, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

We are trying to use a common data for more than one Outlook accounts. Lets say data is stored in a container which belongs to data@outlook.com and I want to read it as datasc1@outlook.com, my friend wants to read from datasc2@outlook.com.

I have common account's storage account name, container name (which is public container) but when I try to read the data using Hive with command below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE deneme (t1 string, t2 string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'wasb://container@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/OUR_DATA.txt';
```

OR I also try command below

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE deneme (t1 string, t2 string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'wasb://container@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/OUR_DATA.txt?sig=ACCESS_KEY_OF_CONTAINER';
```

I get the error below:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException Uploads to to public accounts using anonymous access is prohibited.)
```

We've tried some methods, we made the container type "Public Blob" it didn't work. We added our accounts to storage accounts default directory and it didn't work also. I tried to load data with PIG it seemed to work, but when I dump, PIG also failed.

A weird thing to me is when I run the code below on Hadoop command line it works perfectly :

```
hadoop fs -lsr wasb://container@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/
```

output is :

```
lsr: DEPRECATED: Please use 'ls -R' instead.
-rwxrwxrwx   1  145391417 2015-05-18 10:58 wasb://container@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/OUR_DATA.txt
-rwxrwxrwx   1   25634418 2015-05-18 10:44 wasb://container@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/OUR_OTHER_DATA.txt
```

To sum up up our problem is reading data from another Azure account with our Azure accounts, using HDInsight (Hive/PIG/Hadoop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it work if you just point to the folder instead of a specific file?  Hive expects locations to be folder paths, not specific files.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE deneme (t1 string, t2 string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'wasb://container@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/';
```

I was able to create a similar external table against a container configured as a "Public Container".

If you don't want to use a public container, you can include the storage key in a configuration variable directly in a Hive script like:

```
set fs.azure.account.key.storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net=ACCESS_KEY_OF_CONTAINER;
```

Or you can configure the cluster at provisioning time with access permissions to the storage account using the **Additional Storage Accounts** section of the custom create wizard, or by using the [Add-AzureHDInsightStorage cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757716.aspx) to modify the cluster configuration prior to creating the cluster.

This article has a bunch of related information on the interactions between HDInsight and Azure Blob Storage: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage/

Comment: Worked perfectly, but I have one more question about this. As I've written above in the question I have two files in the folder. How does hive select the right file? Or does just concatenate two files into one external table? Because I need them as seperate tables.

Comment: This question has some details about options for separating things out per-file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269203/when-creating-an-external-table-in-hive-can-i-point-the-location-to-specific-fil  The INPUT__FILE__NAME virtual column will have the full wasb URI of the source file, so if you want to do an exact match, you'd have to do something like:  `select * from deneme WHERE INPUT__FILE__NAME='wasb://container@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/OUR_DATA.txt';`

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by adding below mentioned properties in core-site.xml

```
<property>
        <name>fs.azure.account.key.<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net</name>
        <value><account key value></value>
</property>
```

Now, go to Storage account from **azure portal** and change access type to "**container**" (by default it is "**private**")