# How to load data to hive from HDFS without removing the file

Tags: hive

I have multiple files in single HDFS folder.
I want to load each file into different hive table and want to keep the source files in same location.

I know we can create external table pointing to the directory.

is it possible to create external table pointing to particular file?

Can any one please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a predefined number of files with predefined names, you might try a multi-table INSERT, with WHERE clauses based on the `INPUT__FILE__NAME` virtual column.

```
FROM some_db.some_external_table
INSERT INTO table1
  SELECT a, b, c
  WHERE INPUT__FILE__NAME like '%/gabuzomeu.csv'
INSERT INTO table2
  SELECT a, x, d, CAST(z AS FLOAT)
  WHERE INPUT__FILE__NAME like '%/wtf.csv'
...
```

Reference:

- [when creating an external table in hive can I point the location to specific files in a direcotry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269203/when-creating-an-external-table-in-hive-can-i-point-the-location-to-specific-fil)
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VirtualColumns
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries

Answer (score 0):

External table always has it's own location (a folder). Copy file to table location using  `hadoop distcp <srcurl> <desturl>`  command or  `hdfs dfs -cp ...`. See https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#cp for reference