# Creating external table from file, not directory

Tags: sql, hive, external-tables

When I run the `create external table` query, I have to provide a directory for the 'Location' attribute. But if the directory I point to has more than one file, then it reads both files. For example, if I put `LOCATION 'dir1/'`, and dir1 contains file1 and file2, both files will be read.

To avoid this, I want to point to a single file. When I tried `LOCATION 'dir1/file1'`, it gave me an error that the file path is not a directory or unable to create one. Is there a way to point to just the single file?

Comment: is there an extension/file type for `file1`? If so, you should declare it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when creating an external table in hive can I point the location to specific files in a direcotry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269203/when-creating-an-external-table-in-hive-can-i-point-the-location-to-specific-fil)

Answer (score 0):

If You want to load data from HDFS so try this

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/data/file1' INTO TABLE table1;
```

And if you want to load data from local storage so,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/data/file1' INTO TABLE table1;
```